# Is it possible to get data from RemoteViewsService from AppWidgetProvider?

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to provide a widget for my app and when a user click a button, the app will be opened with the data from `RemoteViewsService`. Is it possible to get it? To setup the list, we need `RemoteViews#setRemoteAdapter`. Is there any like `RemoteViews#getRemoteAdapter`?

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

            Intent itemIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetItemService.class);

            views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.item_list, itemIntent);
            views.setEmptyView(R.id.item_list, R.id.empty);

            Intent buttonIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityA.class);

            //TODO: Something like this
            buttonIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, views.getRemoteAdapter().getData());

            PendingIntent buttonPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, buttonIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, buttonPendingIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if there was a method like *getRemoteAdapter()*, I'd prefer another way of passing the data to the `Activity` from your `AppWidgetProvider`. The main reason for this is security:

Everything you pass as `Intent` extra with `startActivity()` is not private to your application.

`PendingIntent.getActivity()` will call `startActivity()` under the hood, so it's basically the same problem.

But as your `RemoteViewsService` extends from `Service`, you can simply start the `Activity`, and the `Activity` can ask the `Service` for the data you want to display. There are several ways of communication between an `Activity` and a `Service` (e.g. sending local broadcasts via `LocalBroadcastManager`) - it's your choice (although using a bound `Service` may be a good idea because this type seems to be preferred for future android versions)